# LineMark chart display zero values for missing values in Swift Charts

Tags: swift, swiftui, charts

Similar to a chart consisting of `BarMark`, I want my `LineMark` chart to drop to zero if there is no value for a point instead of simply connecting the existing values.

Example:

```
import Charts
import SwiftUI

struct ChartExample: View {
    let data: [(x: Int, y: Int)] = [(0, 1), (1, 3), (5, 1), (10, 1)]
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(data, id: \.x) { point in
                LineMark(x: .value("x", point.x), y: .value("y", point.y))
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ChartExample()
}
```

Resulting LineMark chart:[image]
Wanted LineMark chart:[image]

How can I achieve such behaviour? Do not expect that the entity (number, minute, hour, day…) or the span (1…10, 1 day, 3 months…) is always the same.

Are there any modifiers, or have these points somehow be added manually?

Answer (score 0):

You do need to generate zero marks explicitly, because the SwiftUI charts have no idea *for which X values* the data is missing.

As an example, in your case you do want to interpolate from `x=0` to `x=1`, but not from `x=0` to `x=2`; there is no way to express this logic in SwiftUI Charts.

Code to fill the missing values might look like:

```swift
let data: [(x: Int, y: Int)] = [(0, 1), (1, 3), (5, 1), (10, 1)]

let filledData: [(x: Int, y: Int)] = data.reduce(into: []) { out, point in
    if let last = out.last {
        var xToFill = last.x+1
        while xToFill < point.x {
            out.append((xToFill, 0))
            xToFill += 1
        }
    }
    out.append(point)
        
}
```